# How to filter out logs using Filter with two categories?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using Google Chrome developer tool in Console.

I am aware that I can filter out logs using a "category" at a time, example "Warning", "Debug" and so on.

I am interested to know if there is a way to filter using two "categories" at the same time instead, example I would like to see only "Warning" and "Errors" and not the rest of logs.

Any idea how to achive this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press `Ctrl` and click to select multiple filters.

[image: Multiple selection for console filters]